# How to get the finished action on NSSlider?

Tags: objective-c, macos

There's a NSSlider with code as following

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
NSSlider *slider = sender;
NSInteger value = slider.integerValue;
NSLog(@"%ld",value);
}
```

Because I set `slider.continuous = YES;`, `NSLog` will print in real time, this is right, and I need to add more, except the feature above, I want to get the value when the change is finished, any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remove the second line.  Replace 'slider' with 'sender' on the third line.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

`UISlider` is a subclass of `UIControl`, You can add target and its action for event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. xib[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp1Xl.png)

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender{
UISlider *slider = sender;
NSLog(@"sliderChanged Value = %ld",(long)slider.value);
}

- (IBAction)sliderFinished:(id)sender{
UISlider *slider = sender;
NSLog(@"sliderFinished Value = %ld",(long)slider.value);
}
```

Comment: The question is about `NSSlider`, not `UISlider`.